# Building programs using qmake

Tags: gpl, mit, lgpl

Can I use qmake to build **Non Qt** programs with a closed source or MIT licence?

The c++ code that I'm building does not include any Qt headers or link to any Qt libraries.

The only mention of Qt in any of the projects source files is the following line in the projects .pro file:

```
QT -= core gui widgets
```

I assume using qmake in this way would be just the same as using cmake or gnu make and so would not violate the GPL.

Comment: Are you distributing qmake with the closed source program that you give to your customers?

Comment: Normally you would not distribute qmake (it is only a tool for building), but even if you do, qmake is actually LGPL, which gives you permission even to distribute it together with your closed source products. Basically if you do this you  just need to keep the LGPL part separate from your closed source part and allow a user to replace the verison of LGPL software with her own version if she wants. Unless you go out of your way to make this impossible, this is already the case for a build tool like qmake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt framework - can I (legally) create a commercial app using qmake but not Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223847/qt-framework-can-i-legally-create-a-commercial-app-using-qmake-but-not-qt)

Comment: I'm not distributing qmake, just using it as a tool for building libraries that will be MIT licensed. The libraries will be used in both open and closed source programs. I just wanted to make sure that I would not be polluting the libraries with LGPL restrictions by using qmake.

Comment: Thanks Brandin, you are right it is a duplicate of that.

Comment: Yes. In general, you may use tools. As another example, GNU Make is GPL-licensed, but many people use this tool to build their commercial (closed source) code and it does not cause their code to also be GPLed. The fact that you used a particular tool to build your code does not change the code's license. The only possible problem would be if you copied part of the tool's source code into your project for some reason (unlikely) and then tried to distribute the resulting binaries (i.e. derivative work) as a product without fulfilling the license obligations.